# Can we stop old tags from coming back?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

For example:

1. `Transaction` tags are being replaced with more specific tags
2. `Mining` tags are being  replaced with more specific tags
3. `Sync` are being replaced with `synchronization`

How can we prevent the `transaction` `mining` and `sync` tags from coming back? Is there a mod feature that we can use to block the creation of certain tags?

Not everyone reads the meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are several options, however, chose them wisely.

1A) [Tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/226837) (here's a current [list](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)). If you want to prevent [sync](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) from coming back, and it rather refers to [synchronization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization), just [suggest or create](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) a tag synonym for it. All future questions tagged with [sync](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) will automatically converted to [synchronization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization).

1B) Merge tags. This is basicly merging synonyms. It's the same as 1A with an additional step of retagging (merging) all previously mistagged (e.g., [sync](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync)) with the new tag (e.g., [synchronization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)).

31) [Burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/226837) and [blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/226837) tags. This is a very drastic step and should only apply to obvious generic or [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), like [monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero) (this one should be blacklisted by default). Prior to blacklisting a tag, there needs to be a discussion on the meta here for each single request and it will only happen if there is a broad consensus and the reasons are obvious.

As you can see 1A and 1B are almost the same. And between them and '31' there is a huge gap. For tags like [mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining) or [transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction) I would suggest (if there is *really* consensus that they are too generic) to constantly remove or retag them rather than blacklisting them. Unused tags will be removed from the system every day.

And while we are at it: Don't be scared about [mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining) or [transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction) at this point. In my eyes they are valid. On Ethereum stack exchange there are only 266 transaction questions (9.7%) and 194 mining (7.1%) questions. At this stage it might be also worth to read up through [this meta thread](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/87) from short after the Ethereum public beta launched, and also [this thread](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/87) with a good comment by Robert Cartaino:

> Tags aren't like questions that have too many answers. They are supposed to organize somewhat large swaths of subject matter so folks can find and follow their general interests. Some of those interests are more specific while others remain somewhat general.

Comment: It is interesting to see a different view point. It sounds like we should be cautious before making decisions to block any tags. I liked the mining and transaction retagging effort described here: http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/questions/48/ however I also like your idea of allowing new transaction and mining tags to be used and dealing with them manually for now

Comment: Actually "Burninating" usually refers to extincting a tag, i.e. removing it from every question it appears on. This is appropriate when a tag is useless and there is no valid target for merging. Blacklisting should be seen as a separate tool, which can be used to prohibit creation of a tag. On Bitcoin.SE only two tags are blacklisted: "bitcoin" and "mining". –– 5chdn is right that your experiences with mining and transactions might be completely different than ours. The correct course is probably somewhere in between. :)