# Tags monero-history vs history & monero-research-lab vs mrl

Tags: discussion

These two pairs of tags are coexisting at the moment and one tag of each should be retired.

Regarding [monero-history](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-history) vs [history](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), I prefer [history](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) but I noticed studycrypto have already [edited a question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/posts/858/revisions) to change in the opposite direction and so I prefer to ask.

For [monero-research-lab](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-research-lab) vs [mrl](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mrl), the former is more common (7 vs 2) but I may make sens to keep the complete name since it seems to be used more often in the [site](https://lab.getmonero.org/) and the papers (acronym is mostly used in the papers references such as MRL-0001)

Answer (score 3):

I agree on the `MRL` and `monero-research-labs` synonyms. There are rules about how many times each synonyms has to be tagged before a synonym has been created. So in some cases we may notice a synonym that we cannot create right away until it has been used more.

I agree with your comments about `monero-history` being better as `history` if all `history` were actually about Monero. Are we okay with history questions about other cryptonote coins using the same tag? If we are then `history` is the right tag for sure.

My vote is for `history` being better than `monero-history` and for `MRL` and `monero-research-labs` being created when we are able to do so.

**EDIT: My vote is still recorded above but I found [this post](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/good-tags-now-save-a-lot-of-work-later) this worthy of mentioning.**

Should we have a history tag at all? The definition of history changes all the time. Two years from now people will consider questions about the conversion to RingCT `history`. Is `history` too ambiguous for us to use?

> ambiguous tags, e.g. future, computing, offline

Comment: Good point about history being a moving target. Maybe "genesis" fits better, since those questions typically about the genesis of a project, and also has this lame pun built-in...

Comment: @user36303 I like the "genesis" tag better too. Seems more appropriate for a long term solution

Comment: @user36303 when doing a search for the history tag I see both "origins" and "inceptions" used in question titles. Might either of those be more common search terms than "genesis"? http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history

Comment: I just made edits to replace monero-history with history (sound like we have an agreement that we should not have both). Once we can reach an agreement about genesis vs origin, etc we can replace history with that,

Comment: Hmm, I like origin too. And it maybe more widely understood than genesis.

Comment: @user36303 I also like origin. Should we depreciate the history tag too? There are already some historical questions that are too recent to be origin questions. Maybe that is okay since "history" is kind of a meta tag where the other questions would be more important anyway. At best the "history" tag helps serve as a warning that the answer if applied today may no longer be accurate. At worst "history" serves no purpose

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the short ones in both cases.

For history, it's obvious it's about monero. Same for monero-hard-fork -> hard-fork.

For mrl, it's more subjective, but since we can have synonyms, I'd keep the short and easy one, and set up monero-research-labs as a synonym.

Comment: so we go with plain "history" then ? I've got edit requests pending to change from monero-history to history

Comment: @JollyMort I think we agreed that was better than monero-history. The question should not be if we should switch to "origin" and if so, what we should do with "history" tags that don't fit that description.