# Improving tag wikis and usage guidance

Tags: discussion, tagging

Based on the success of a similar effort on [Ethereum SE](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381/lets-improve-our-top-tag-wikis-and-usage-guidance-for-new-users) lets apply the same process developed by 5chdn here.

## Priority List

#### Tags used more than 25 times**

These tags should have both a **good usage guidance** and a **well-described tag wiki**.

1. [monero-wallet-cli](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-wallet-cli) missing tag wiki
2. [monerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod) missing tag wiki
3. [security](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) missing tag wiki
4. [ringct](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringct) missing tag wiki
5. [mnemonic-seed](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic-seed) weak tag wiki
6. [full-node](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-node) missing tag wiki
7. [privacy](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
8. [blockchain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blockchain) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
9. [gpu-mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpu-mining) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
10. [cpu-mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-mining) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki

#### Tags used more than 10 times

These tags should *at least* have a **good usage guidance**. Once we have a well described wiki for all of our priority tags above we can work on adding a wiki for these tags too.

1. [hard-fork](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-fork) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
2. [cryptonote](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptonote) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
3. [cold-storage](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage) missing usage guidance, missing tag wiki
4. [cpu-mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-mining) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
5. [transaction-fees](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-fees) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
6. [wallet-recovery](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wallet-recovery) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
7. [viewkey](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewkey) missing tag wiki
8. [ring-signatures](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-signatures) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
9. [mining-pools](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-pools) missing tag wiki
10. [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
11. [mymoneo](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mymoneo) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
12. [gui](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
13. [development](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
14. [synchronization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
15. [transaction-confirmation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-confirmation) missing tag wiki
16. [transaction-data](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transaction-data)  weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
17. [monero-research-lab](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-research-lab)  weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
18. <del>[monero-core](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-core)</del> *tag depreciated due to inconsistent usage*
19. [kovri](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kovri)  weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
20. [stealth-address](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth-address) missing tag wiki
21. [history](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
22. [cryptocurrency-comparison](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptocurrency-comparison) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
23. [cryptography](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
24. [aeon](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aeon) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
25. [testnet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testnet) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
26. [rpc](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpc) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
27. [mining-theory](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-theory) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
28. [multisig](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisig) missing tag wiki
29. [hashrate](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashrate) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki
30. [integrated-address](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrated-address) weak usage guidance, missing tag wiki

List and tag status above is incomplete and will be updated over time. The complete list of current tags can be [found here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags)

**How to help**

Go through the list of tags above and see if you can help out creating or improving both the usage guidance and the tag wiki.

> **Usage guidance**, also known as a tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.
>
> **Tag wikis** help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.

The usage guidance, is in my eyes the most important, as this is the popout a user reads while tagging a question.

Note, Ethereum SE performed a similar challenge in March pretty successfully. We can learn from [their guidance](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/lets-create-tag-excerpts-and-wiki-entries) on this process.

See also: [Good Tags now save a lot of work later!](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/good-tags-now-save-a-lot-of-work-later)

Comment: Feel free to make suggestions about how to modify tags to encourage more appropriate usage. For example monero-core (which is missing usage guidance) has been used in both GUI related questions (https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core#about-this-project) and in completely other contexts.

Comment: Should we eliminate the monero-core tag to reduce confusion? A few questions where only it was used need to be retagged but I think we can live without out.

Comment: @SmartKid yes as currently used I think we are better off without the monero-core tag. Lets wait and see if anyone proposes another idea.

Comment: @SmartKid I will help change the tags in the monero-code questions so that it can be depreciated if needed.