# GUI tag discussion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

`monero-core` [failed](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/improving-tag-wikis-and-usage-guidance) as a SE tag because its usage was not always consistent with its intended meaning. For that reason I was happy to see this [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/299/files) today from [moneromooo-monero](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero) with the intention of changing (in the source code not on SE) `monero-core` to `monero-wallet-gui`

We could do the following for SE:

1. Adopt `monero-wallet-gui` as a synonym for `gui` for questions about the "official" Monero GUI.
2. Give `jaxx` and other popular 3rd party GUI wallets their own tag so it is clear what each tag refers to.

How do others feel about this? If you like this proposal do you prefer `monero-wallet-gui` (long but similar to our `monero-wallet-cli` tag) or `gui` as the "master" [synonym](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)?

**EDIT**: I like some aspects of the [proposal](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/7) from xmr_eric below but have a few more questions:

1. Will the definition of `official-gui` and `3rd-party-gui` get blurred over time if more wallets are funded by the [Forum Funding System](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-you-propose-a-project-with-the-forum-funding-system)?
2. If we wait until a 3rd party wallet receives enough questions to "earn" its its own tag, what should that threshold be?
3. By providing specific tags to some popular 3rd party wallets such as `jaxx` while forcing others to use a generic `3rd-party-wallet` tag will we offend any developers or make some questions harder to find? Based on the historical usage of `monero-wallet-cli` new `gui` related tags are likely to eventually become some of the most popular tags on Monero SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I propose a hybrid answer, sourcing from the first two suggestions.

I think `monero-wallet-gui` would be the best tag for the official GUI, since it provides for basically a one-to-one correlation with `monero-wallet-cli`, both in the file name and the tag name.

I think `third-party-wallets` is a logical tag for all third-party wallets, whether GUI or not.  I lean slightly in preference of spelling out `third`, rather than using `3rd`.  Then again, if the interest is in going short, then `3rd-party` with no mention of `wallets` may be best.

I think specific tags for third-party wallets (such as `jaxx`) are fine and useful, as long as there are several instances of a given tag.  I think it's natural for this type of forum to require periodic housekeeping, so perhaps one-time- or two-time-use tags should be purged after six months or a year or whatever.  (That is, to answer the 'threshold' question, I think two or three should be the threshold, but I think the tag should be able to be generated by  users with enough rep, just as tags are created otherwise; and we'll just do periodic housekeeping to clean up the stale ones.)

I will also lastly point out that some suggestions here may appear better than other partly due to the timescale involved.  For example, in the future there may be value in using tags to distinguish community-funded and/or core dev-reviewed 3rd-party wallets from 3rd-party wallets that did not go through those channels.  It's unclear to me exactly how much this line of thinking should weigh on the current discussion.

Comment: +1 "third-party-wallets" not "3rd-party-wallets"

Answer (score 4):

What about delineating it between "official GUI" and "3rd-party GUIs"? After all, there could eventually hundreds of third party GUIs, and each one shouldn't get its own tag.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to have many tags to 3rd-party GUIs ? Question for a specific GUI are usually not relevant for other ones so it make sens to have specific tags.

Comment: xmr_eric, i think we should never use the word "official" without naming the authority behind it (Core Official GUI). Otherwise, It feels like there is a centralized authority governing

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion:

- monero-wallet-cli - meaning "core" CLI
- monero-wallet-gui - meaning "core" GUI
- monero-wallet-software - meaning "any wallet". Could be used together with the 1st 2 tags, or used alone for anything not "core".

Comment: I get an impression from the name `monero-wallet-xxx` that it's from the core team and `xxx` represents the type of the software; `cli`, `gui` and `rpc` represent the type of the wallet software. `monero-wallet-software` sounds quite strange as it doesn't fit logically well with the others. Also it doesn't carry so much of useful information since all binaries are "software" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, my preference is the shorter the better. "Official Gui" anyone?

Comment: official-gui may be a good tag synonym but the highest voted tag suggestion is based on names from monero source code

Answer (score 1):

I think `monero-wallet-cli` and `monero-core-gui` are very good labels for the official software, because they also match the program name. Yesterday, I created a question for the GUI, and was literally looking for `monero-wallet-gui`, only to find `gui` so far which feels a bit too vague (because what does it mean? daemon, client, explorer, ...?).

For anything else, I'd suggest to use `wallet-software` or `mining-software`, in my opinion no need to prefix with `monero-` because obviously this is 99% about Monero here.

And for specific software, say if Jaxx or Exodus becomes popular, we could of course change those to `jaxx-wallet` or `exodus-wallet`, but that would likely need to be revisit on a case-by-case basis if there are enough questions to justify such a dedicated label.